Unable to open the CVS Airdrop app in Safe WALLET
I get the following error when I try to open the CSV Airdrop App from Safe WALLET:
The web page at https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmTpg77NY45oyx2Qtsa8WXCDby3qeKrCCNjr4JUJekSsyR might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

The support at help.safe.global directed me here.

I am also having an issue with CSV Airdrop through Safe. I receive this error: "ipfs.io refused to connect."

it looks like this is a bug from Safe{Wallet) when trying to access this app from a safe which has not been deployed yet. Could you please try with a deployed safe and confirm it solved the problem?
Please let me know! Thanks in advance  Louis

Hi Louis, thanks for your comment. I tried to launch the app again from the same safe and was able to. Not sure what made the difference.

Thanks for the update. Could you tell me what network your safe was deployed to? And confirm it was actually deployed? It will help us investigate. Thanks!
